Куда размещать свой собственный прописанный сервер для мобильного приложения. Мобильное приложение написано на expo react native
Написал мобильное приложение на expo react native. Под него написал сервер. Локально сервер запускается и все отлично работает. Но встал вопрос. Куда я должен поместить мой сервер, что бы он был не локальным, а глобальным (обычный хостинг для сайтов подойдет?)

Вам нужен хостер, который умеет размещать бэк на вашей технологии(java, node, php). Если коробочных решений нет, то наверняка можно найти VPS с возможностью запустить там нужный вам приклад

Да, хостинг провайдер подойдёт
